# Impossible to boot on encrypted root partition after 15.10 upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

Since I upgraded my system to 15.10 it freezes just after I type and validate the root partition password:

1. EFI Boot
2. Grub2 Panel
3. System ask password for the root partition
4. User type and press Enter
5. System stops, without message, no disk activity

I tried all grub entry without any success (kernel 4.2 and 3.19, systemd, upstart and repair).

I can still mount my partitions from a live CD 15.10. Then I tried various fix with a chroot:

- Add more dm-crypt relative module in **/etc/initramfs-tools/modules** file
- Fix various iniramfs warning (like locale warning)
- Launch `update-grub` and `update-initramfs -u -k all` without warning

Since it happens just after the root partition unkocking, there's no logs.

---

The configuration :

```
/dev/mapper/crypt_root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/crypt_home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=4,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4039992k,nr_inodes=1009998,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=810576k,mode=755)
```

Cryptsetup:

```
/dev/mapper/crypt_root is active and is in use. 
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 512 bits
  device:  /dev/sdb3
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    491304960 sectors
  mode:    read/write
/dev/mapper/crypt_home is active and is in use.
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
  keysize: 256 bits
  device:  /dev/sda7
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    1130182656 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

**/etc/initramfs-tools/modules**

```
cryptoloop
aes
sha256
aes-x86_64
sha512-ssse3
dm-mod
dm-crypt
```

Update logs:

```
# update-initramfs -u -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-17-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic

# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-17-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

---

Bibliography:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal
- http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu
- https ://codeghar.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/linux-mint-warning-no-support-for-locale-en_us-utf-8-in-update-initramfs/
- http ://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178666/sbin-cryptsetup-not-found-on-boot
- https ://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: I opened a bug on cryptsetup on launchpad [cryptsetup blocks between mountroot and bottom in initramfs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1513415).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed for me.

1. boot on a live DVD
2. mount the root partition and devices, then chroot
3. reinstall **lvm2** that was removed during the 15.10 upgrade
4. remove all local diversions
5. reinstall **dmsetup** to add a missing udev script in initramfs (**55-dm.rules**) => [that cause this freeze](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/224340231/cryptsetup-debug.txt)
6. reboot

Comment: great !! Could you please provide a more detailed step by step? Thanks,